# I want to get Java Edition a different device. Will the progress be the same?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I used to play on a iPad for Minecraft Bedrock Edition, but I want to play on a computer. My parents will only allow me to pick one of the two editions, Bedrock or Java.

If I use the same account on both editions, will the worlds and the progress on servers be the same?

Comment: You keep referring to Bedrock Edition as "regular".  Are you aware that the Java Edition predates Bedrock Edition (and any of its previous incarnations such as Pocket Edition and XBox Edition) by many years?  To most people, Java Edition is the regular version.

Answer (score 0):

No, worlds are not cross-compatible between Java and Bedrock editions. You may use an external program to convert a world between the two editions but this may break some things or cause them to function differently. For example, redstone functions differently between Java and Bedrock editions. Converting your world may cause the mechanisms to break.

Worlds are also not synced between editions, and are stored locally per your device, not on the account level.

In your case, you're going to have to pick an edition, lock in your choice, and wait until your parents will let you buy the other.

Comment: To add to this, redstone on Bedrock and Java function differently, so if you've been building redstone devices you will likely find that converting the world will break them.

Comment: @JonK Oh yes, very important to note that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way to mix Java and Bedrock content and multiplayer. I can help you out with certain ways on how you can go about getting progress if you buy the Bedrock version.

If you play using Bedrock on PC with the same Microsoft account as your iPad, you should be able to use a realm to move worlds to your PC version. Note that a realm costs money, and unless you saved your 30-day free trial, there is no other way that I am aware of that is fully supported by Mojang.

As a side note, anything you bought in the Marketplace AFTER the better together update is transferred for free as long as the same Microsoft account is used. And, if you play on servers, all progress and personalization should sync as long as the same Microsoft account.

(This is my first answer. Please let me know how I can improve the quality of my posts)